# QTreeView extended selection and removal/moving multiple items

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, qtreeview, model-view

Is it permissible to implement below removal algorithm for `QTreeView`, where `QTreeView::setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection);`, i.e. multiple items is selectable?

```
QModelIndexList indexList = treeView->selectionModel()->selectedRows();
QList< QPersistentModelIndex > persistentIndexList;
for (QModelIndex const & index : indexList) {
    persistentIndexList.append(index);
}
for (QPersistentModelIndex const & persistentIndex : persistentIndexList) {
    if (!treeModel->removeRow(persistentIndex.row(), persistentIndex.parent())) {
        qWarning() << "Can't remove row" << persistentIndex;
    }
}
```

I think, it is possible the situation, when parent removed before the child and even persistent indexes are not valid at that moment. Am I wrong?

Must the model to check `hasIndex` in `removeRows`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every implementation of `QAbstractItemModel` does its best (at least it has to) to keep `QPersistentModelIndex`s valid when the model is changed. If the model can't calculate new location of the index it invalidates the `QPersistentModelIndex`. It can happen when the index is removed or a model layout or whole data was changed.

That is why it's always neccessary to check if `QPersistentModelIndex` valid or not before using it.

But `QAbstractItemModel::removeRows` returns `bool`. It means that wrong arguments can be passed to this method. If the model can't remove rows due to wrong arguments it returns `false`.

So the answer to your question is **yes**, you should check an index in `removeRows` and return correct result.

Comment: So, I may or may not add the `persistentIndex.isValid()` check to decide may I call the `treeModelTranfsormations->removeRow(persistentIndex.row(), persistentIndex.parent())`?

Comment: Generally, you don't need this check, because if the index was invalidated, then `row` returns -1 and `parent` returns an invalid index. Thus the check inside the removeRows is enough. Of course you may call it if you want. It will work also.